# QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: web.login

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I installed odoo 9, and each time i try to run it, this error appears:

```
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
QWebTemplateNotFound: External ID not found in the system: web.login
```

All the modules in requirements.txt were installed including passlib,i also tried to clear history and kill servers. I've created the db role by following this steps:

```
sudo adduser odoo
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo su postgresql
createuser --createdb --username postgres --no-createrole --no-superuser -pwprompt odoo
```

so what did i miss?

updated

---

here's openerp-server.config file:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons
```

i also tried this command and it's not working:

```
python odoo.py --addons addons
```

and

```
./odoo.py --addons-path=.../Desktop/odoo/addons
```

Comment: Can you post your config file, or the command line you're using to execute it? You need to specify your addons_path, for instance "addons_path = /your_path_here/odoo/addons".

Comment: @Lucas updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your addons are not loading when you are starting the server.
What you can do is manually load addons when starting the server:

```
./odoo-bin --addons=addons/
```

Comment: i tried python odoo.py --addons addons but it's not working, how to revert ?

Comment: You can also try
./odoo-bin --load=web --addons=addons/

Also if it still not works, please comment the full stack trace.

Comment: Note: You have to try the above commands after killing the existing running server with '-9' key. And the command will work inside the odoo directory where you have cloned the repository.

Comment: i don't have bin  file  in odoo so i can't use it.

Comment: The odoo-bin file is the same as openerp-server

Answer (score 0):

To access odoo instance from a browser ***web*** module is required . So you have to load all the modules and load **web** module externally.

There are two ways for that:-

1.Load everything as an argument itself

```
./odoo-bin -d db_name -r db_user -w db_pass --load=web --addons=addons1,addons2
```

2.Provide a configuration file for above task like this

```
./odoo-bin -c config-file
```

This config-file will look like this:-

```
db_host             = False
db_port             = False
db_user             = deepak
db_password         = d33p@k
db_name             = proj_db

addons_path         = addons1,addons2
server_wide_modules = web
```

Here **odoo-bin** is the name of odoo executable for Odoo 10. Change it as per your Odoo version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing manualy web and base

```
./odoo-bin -i web,base
```